# Refer python variables using two other variables

Tags: python, variables, global

I have fixed variables :

```
apple_weight = 50
mango_weight = 100
veggie1 = apple
veggie2 = mango
```

I want to be able to refer the weight variables by using the veggie variables in my code :

```
whatcomeshere = globals()[[str(veggie1) + str(_weight)]]

print("The weight of the veggie {}, is {}").format(veggie1, whatcomeshere)
```

I am trying to use the globals statement as above but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-bceaa9070b38>", line 3, in <module>
    veggie1 = apple

NameError: name 'apple' is not defined
```

Comment: You shold seriously think about using a dedicated dictionary, rather than butchering the `globals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apple` and `mango` are interpreted as variables that do not exist. You mean to define them as string literals. See below:

```py
apple_weight = 50
mango_weight = 100
veggie1 = 'apple'
veggie2 = 'mango'
```

You might find it easier to use a simple data type like a dictionary to encapsulate this structure rather than finagling the global namespace.

```py
APPLE_CDE = 'apple'
MANGO_CDE = 'mango'
d = {
  APPLE_CDE: {'weight': 50},
  MANGO_CDE: {'weight': 100}
}
w = d.get(APPLE_CDE, {}).get('weight', None)
print(w)
```

Comment: There's also a similar problem with `str(_weight)` which should be `"_weight"`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because the name `apple` is not declared or defined before referencing it in the line `veggie1`. I assume you want `veggie1` to be the string apple so you would need to

`veggie1 = "apple"`

For the issue of refering to other variables, you can't directly build the names of variables like you are in

`[str(veggie1) + str(_weight)]`

Edit: skullgoblet1089's Answer shows a good way to use a dictionary to do what you are doing

What this will return is `[apple50]` which is I presume is not what you want. You need to explicitly call `apple_weight`.

If you want to generate variable names you would want to use a dictionary and then generate strings as keys for the dictionary.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp